# Desenho com cv::circle's sobre uma linha Iteradora em c++ com openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator

Estou criando uma linha iteradora, em que passo depois por um `for()` e vou desenhando com pontos `cv::circle`. Até aí tudo bem, ele forma um desenho de linha, pelos pontos da linha ieradora.
Mas fica **um pequeno desenho na parte superior esquerda** que não é minha itenção, alguém sabe onde posso estar errando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
std::vector<cv::Point> createLineIterator(cv::Mat &frame)
{
    cv::Point p1(400, 0);
    cv::Point p2(200, 800);

    cv::LineIterator line(frame, p1, p2, 8);
    std::vector<cv::Point> points(line.count);
    for (int i = 0; i <= line.count; i++, ++line)
    {
        points.push_back(line.pos());
    }
    return points; //pontos que vou iterar para criar circulos e desenhar a linha
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image(500, 1000, CV_8UC1); // cria imagem

    std::vector<cv::Point> points = createLineIterator(image);
    for (auto i : points)
    {
        cv::circle(image, i, 2, cv::Scalar(255, 100, 255)); // Desenho ponto por ponto da linha iteradora
    }

    cv::imshow("image", image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui retornando cv::Point na função

```
std::pair<std::pair<cv::Point, cv::Point>, std::vector<cv::Point>> createLineIterator(cv::Mat &frame){...}
```

e eu chamei na main

```
cv::line(image, points.first.first, points.first.second, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não descobri o motivo do erro antes ao desenhar com `cv::circle`, mas veja que o desenho aleatório não existe mais com `cv::line`